# Nested For Loop, Replace If statement

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I have been practicing my nested for loops recently. I tried building a 5x5 block of coordinates going from (0,0) to (5,5). Each row will go up to y = 5 and then start a new row.

Here is the code I have built, it does what I want it to do, the only problem is that I had to use an if statement. Is there another for loop I could use to make it so that I don't have to use the if statement?

```
public class NestedLoops3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int counter =0;counter<6;counter++) {
        for(int counter2 = 0;counter2<6;counter2++)
             {  
            System.out.print("("+counter+","+counter2+")");
            if(counter2==5) {
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
}
}
}
```

As it is right now it does what I intended but I just want to see if I can replace the if statement with another for loop.

Comment: If statements add almost no overhead to your code. Whats the problem with it?

Comment: I just wanted to do it with for loops. I knew it was possible was just stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Move the `println` after the nested loop. Like,

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < 6; counter++) {
    for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < 6; counter2++) {  
        System.out.print("(" + counter + "," + counter2 + ")");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `System.out.println();` outside the nested for loop

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest writing an if statement with a for loop :)

While writing the new line after the loop works, for a square grid, you could use a single loop and calculate the row and column

```
int size = 5;

for(int counter =0;counter<(size*size)+1;counter++) {
    int col = counter % size;
    int row = counter / size;
    System.out.printf("(%d, %d) ", row, col);
    if(col == size) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

```
public class NestedLoops3 {
    void main(String[] args) {
        for(int counter =0;counter<6;counter++) {
            for(int counter2 = 0;counter2<6;counter2++) {  
                System.out.print("("+counter+","+counter2+")");
                for (; counter2 == 5; ) {
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't see the reason to do so. The middle part of a for-loop is a condition and can be used for that purpose. To avoid side effects, I abstained from setting the counter2 to 6 for instance, break the loop without break statement, but since the scope of counter2 is limited, this would be valid as well:

```
            for(int counter2 = 0;counter2<6;counter2++) {  
                System.out.print("("+counter+","+counter2+")");
                for (; counter2 == 5; counter2=6) {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
```

Since such style is very uncommon, it is error prone, should somebody try to extend the code, setting the middle loop to run to 7 for example.

But possible, yes, it is.

Output:

```
-> main (null) 
(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)
(1,0)(1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(1,5)
(2,0)(2,1)(2,2)(2,3)(2,4)(2,5)
(3,0)(3,1)(3,2)(3,3)(3,4)(3,5)
(4,0)(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)(4,5)
(5,0)(5,1)(5,2)(5,3)(5,4)(5,5)
```